# Spring cloud stream rabbitMQ consumer partition

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I created a sample HttpSource and HttpSink. My application.properties looks like this

```
Source
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=greetings
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.partitionKeyExpression=payload
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.partitionCount=2


Sink
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=greetings
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.partitioned=true
spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount=2
spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex=0
```

HttpSource

```
@RestController
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
 public class SampleSource {

 @Autowired
 private MessageChannel output;

 @RequestMapping(path="/message",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public void sendMessage(@RequestBody String name){
    output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello, "+name).build());
 }
}
```

HttpSink

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class SampleSink {

 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel=Sink.INPUT)
 public void sendMessage(String name){
    System.out.println(name);
 }
}
```

I deployed both these apps to Pivotal Cloud Foundry. The HttpSource has an endpoint which on calling sends message to a Topic exchange called "greetings". Then I scaled the HttpSink to have 2 instances. This created two queues and bindings to "greetings" exchange.

Now when I hit the endpoint, I find that the message is sent to both the queues. I know this because I tailed the log and found that the message is printed twice.

How can I make the message go to only one of the queues?

EDIT:

Instead of scaling the HttpSink within Pivotal Cloud Foundry, I deployed HttpSink as two different apps. But in the application.properties they belonged to the same group. One of them had instanceIndex=0 and the other intanceIndex=1.

Even now, I get a single queue with binding as "#" and two consumers to that queue.

How can I make different instances of HttpSink create their own queue and the message from HttpSource gets routed to one of them based on the partitionKey?

Comment: What do the queue bindings look like in the Rabbit UI? The 2 queues should be bound to the exchange with routing keys appended with `-0`, `-1` which is how the producer sets up the routing key on outbound messages. On the consumer side, each instance needs a difference `instanceIndex`.

Comment: The queues have binding "#" for both. I was under the impression that if I scaled the number of instances using Pivotal cloud foundry then it'd take care of the instanceIndex

Comment: You need to set a consumer group for partitioned consumers. Anonymous consumers get all messages via #.

Comment: I added group to the consumer application.properties. 

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=swarm1

This caused creation of one queue, by the name "greetings.swarm1" and two consumers for that queue. But the queue still has the binding as "#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice before - you are missing `consumer.` from the property:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.partitioned=true
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_configuring_input_bindings_for_partitioning).

Are you using an IDE to create the properties file? My version of STS (3.8.1) flagged this as an issue when I copied in your properties.

I just ran a test and the queue is correctly named and bound to the exchange with the correct key.

**EDIT**

To get it to scale properly on PCF, I also had to comment out the `instanceIndex` property (presumably because it overrides the PCF environment property) otherwise I got 2 consumers on the `-0` queue. With that property removed I got 2 queues as expected.

Comment: You're right. I missed "consumer." in HttpSink. Also I missed "producer." in HttpSource. And commented out indexInstance too